# JSON - Permission Error?

Tags: posts, ajax, json

I have two dropdowns to filter posts on a website. The second dropdown populates based on the selection of the first, ie:

```
[CATEGORY] + [SUB-CATEGORY] = SEARCH
```

The problem is that occasionally the second dropdown won't populate, and the console shows:

```
POST: http://localhost/site/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
{"html":"","error":"Permission error"}
```

What does that actually mean? And how would I go about fixing it? This is the code that returns the error:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt', 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt', 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt' );

function wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt() {
$ret = array( 'html' => '', 'error' => false );

if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'wpse158929_get_terms_for_cpt_submit_', 'nonce', false /*die*/ ) ) {
$ret['error'] = __( 'Permission error', 'wpfm' );
} else {
$post_type = isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ? $_REQUEST['post_type'] : '';
$taxonomy = isset( $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] ) ? $_REQUEST['taxonomy'] : '';
$current_selected = isset( $_REQUEST['current_selected'] ) ? $_REQUEST['current_selected'] : '';

if ( ! $post_type || ! $taxonomy ) {
    $ret['error'] = __( 'Params error', 'wpfm' );
} else {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( 'SELECT t.slug FROM ' . $wpdb->terms . ' t'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->posts . ' AS p ON p.ID = tr.object_id'
        . ' WHERE tt.taxonomy = %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = %s'
        . ' GROUP BY t.slug'
        , $taxonomy, $post_type, 'publish' );
    $include = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    $ret['html'] = preg_replace( '/<\/?select[^>]*>/', '', my_dropdown_categories( $taxonomy, $current_selected, $include ) );
}
}

wp_send_json( $ret );
}
```

Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are checking for nonce and the nonce is stale. It is hard to make a specific comment about the need of using nonce in your case, but in general nonces should be used only for data submission not query.